# C++ - Writing binary data to eof fails

Tags: c++, binary

I am currently trying to write binary data using C++. The to be written data should be in the middle of other already written data. The to be written data is just zero bytes.

## Code

My code looks like that:

```
unsigned int length = 4;
unsigned int offset = 0;

string path = "test.bin";

fstream file;
file.open(path, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::ate);
queue <char*> buffers;

bool allocated = false;

do {
    file.seekg(offset);
    cout << "Reading buffer items! Offset: " << file.tellg() << endl;
    char* buffer = new char[length];
    file.read(buffer, length);

    if (file.gcount() != 0) {
        buffers.push(buffer);
    }

    if (allocated) {
        cout << "#1 Writing buffer items! Offset: " << file.tellp() << endl;
        file.seekp(offset, ios::end);
        cout << "#2 Writing buffer items! Offset: " << file.tellp() << endl;
        char* writeBuffer = buffers.front();
        buffers.pop();
        file.write(writeBuffer, length);
    } else {
        file.seekp(offset);
        cout << "Writing null bytes! Offset: " << file.tellp() << endl;
        char* buffer = new char[length];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (char) 0x00;
        }
        file.write(buffer, length);
        allocated = true;
    }

    offset += length;
} while (file.gcount() != 0 && !buffers.empty());

file.flush();
file.close();
```

Given the `test.bin` looks like that:

`0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x44`

## Output

My current output on std is

```
Reading buffer items! Offset: 0
Writing null bytes! Offset: 0
Reading buffer items! Offset: 4
#1 Writing buffer items! Offset: -1
#2 Writing buffer items! Offset: -1
Reading buffer items! Offset: -1
#1 Writing buffer items! Offset: -1
#2 Writing buffer items! Offset: -1
```

And the file looks like that:

`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x44`

I have no clue why it does not write the "shifted" part of the binary file but the zero bytes and why it does not set the position of the output sequence properly.

Edit:

Here is the expected file output: `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x44`

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I added it :) thanks for your question

Comment: *"The to be written data is just zero bytes."* - Er. Why do you need **any** code to implement a no-op?

Comment: I just want to do the shifting of the data while I generate the data that really needs to be written. I put there zero bytes in because they can overwritten afterwards without issues.